# Nginx: Add context if one doesn't exist - in redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

**Requirement:**

Redirect http://ruby.server.com to https://ruby.server.com/app1/ and don't append anything if the incoming URL has context (ex: http://ruby.server.com/app2/) in it

**Setup**

We have the following setup

Amazon Load Balancer

```
| http -  |
          | --> 80(ruby.server.com)
| https - |
```

nginx is running on ruby.server.com at port 80. There is no 443 in nginx.

```
 server {
     listen 80;
     server_name  ruby.server.com;
     root /home/ubuntu/ruby/server/public/;
     location / {
        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
            rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }
         client_max_body_size 100M;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4009/;
         root /home/ubuntu/ruby/server/public/;
   }
```

> if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') line is used for redirecting http://ruby.server.com to https://ruby.server.com

**More context**

We have 2 rails apps running inside the rails server, /public/app1, /public/app2. By default we want to redirect ruby.server.com to go to app1.

We can solve the above problem within the rails itself that involves an additional redirection. We are trying to see if we can get that context append within the nginx layer.

**Solution based @timothy's note.**

```
server {
     listen 80;
     server_name  ruby.server.com;
     root /home/ubuntu/staging/server/public/;
     location / {
        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
            rewrite ^ https://$host/app1/? permanent;
        }

         client_max_body_size 100M;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4009/;
         root /home/ubuntu/staging/server/public/;
         #auth_basic "Restricted";
         #auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
    location ^~ /[^\/]+/ {
        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
            rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }

        client_max_body_size 100M;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4009/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should `http://ruby.server.com/app2/` become `https://...`?

Comment: @tomofey yes. http -> https required for all URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  ruby.server.com;
    root /home/ubuntu/ruby/server/public/;

    location / {
        # Default location for:
        #     http://ruby.server.com
        #     https://ruby.server.com

        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
            rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }
        client_max_body_size 100M;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4009/;
    }
    location ^~ /[^\/]+/ {
        # Location for:
        #    http://ruby.server.com/anything/
        #    https://ruby.server.com/anything/

        # Do whatever you need here. :)

        client_max_body_size 100M;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4009/;
    }
}
```